# Service access Entity attributes

Tags: oop, domain-driven-design, encapsulation, ddd-service

In oop we seek to **encapsulation**. We try not to expose internal state via getters or by public fields, only expose methods.

So far so good.

In situation when we would like to operate on multiple **Entities** we introduce **Service**.
But how this service can operate freely on these entities?

If all (both Service and Entities) were in the same package, Entities could expose package private methods or fields and Service could use them, preserving encapsulation. But what when Entities and Service are from different packages? It seems that Entities should either expose public getters (first step to anemic model and leackage of logic from Entities), or public methods executing logic that is specific to the needs of service, possibly introduced only by requirements of this service - also seems bad. How to tackle this?

Answer (score 1):

In the context of OO, the most important thing for you to understand is that **objects respond to messages**, and that in OO**P** in particular, **methods are how these responses are implemented**.

For example, imagine you have a `Person` object to which you (as the programmer) have assigned the responsibility to respond to the "grow" message. Generally, you would implement that as a `Person.grow()` method, like this.

```
class Person {
    int age;

    public void grow() { this.age++; }
}
```

This seems fairly obvious, but you must note that from the message sender's perspective, how `Person` object reacts is meaningless. For all it cares, the method `Person.grow()` could be triggering a missile launch, and it would not matter because some other object (or objects) could be responding in the right way (for example, a UI component updating itself on the screen). However, *you* decided that when the `Person` object handles the "grow" message, it must increment the value of its age attribute. This is encapsulation.

So, to address your concern, *"public methods executing logic that is specific to the needs of service, possibly introduced only by requirements of this service - also seems bad"*, it is not bad at all because you are designing the entities to respond to messages from the services in specific ways to match the requirements of your application. The important thing to bear in mind is that the services do not dictate how the entities behave, but rather the entities respond in their own way to requests from the services.

Finally, you might be asking yourself: *how do entities know that they need to respond to certain messages?* This is easy to answer: *YOU* decide how to link messages to responses. In other  words, you think about the requirements of your application (what "messages" will be sent by various objects) and how they will be satisfied (how and which objects will respond to messages).

Answer (score 0):

> In situation when we would like to operate on multiple Entities we introduce Service.

No we don't. Well, I guess some people do, but the point is they *shouldn't*.

In object-orientation, we model a particular problem domain. We don't (again, shouldn't) discriminate based on what amount of other objects a single object operates. If I have to model an `Appointment` and a collection of `Appointment` I don't introduce an `AppointmentService`, I introduce a `Schedule` or `Timetable`, or whatever is appropriate for the domain.

The distinction of `Entity` and `Service` is not domain-conform. It is purely technical and most often a regression into procedural thinking, where an `Entity` is data and the `Service` is a procedure to act on it.

DDD as is practiced today is not based on OOP, it just uses object syntax. One clear indication is that in most projects entities are directly persisted, even contain database ids or database-related annotations.

So either do OOP *or* do DDD, you can't really do both. [Here](https://javadevguy.wordpress.com/2018/11/26/video-german-object-oriented-domain-driven-design-talk/) is a talk of mine (talk is german but slides are in english) about OO and DDD.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the usage of getters as a step towards an anaemic model. Or at least, as everything in programming, it depends.
Downside of anaemic model is that every component accessing the object can *mutate* it without any enforcing of its invariants (opening to possible inconsistency in data), it can be done easily using the setter methods.

(I will use the terms command and query to indicate methods that modify the state of the objects and methods that just return data without changing anything)

The point of having an aggregate/entity is to enforce the object invariants, so it exposes "command" methods that don't reflect the internal structure of the object, but instead are "domain oriented" (using the "ubiquitous language" for their naming), exposing its "domain behavior" (an avoidance of get/set naming is suggested because they are standard naming for representing the object internal structure).

This is for what concern the *set* methods, what about *get*?
As set methods can be seen as "command" of the aggregate, you can see the getters as "query" methods used to ask data to the aggregate. Asking data to an aggregate is totally fine, if this doesn't break the responsability of the aggregate of enforcing invariants. This means that you should watch out to what the query method returns.
If the query method result is a **value** object, so, immutable, it is totally fine to have it. In this way who query the aggregate has in return something that can be only read.
So you could have query methods doing calculation using the object internal state (eg. A method `int missingStudents()` that calculate the number of missing student for a `Lesson` entity that has the `totalNumber` of students and a `List<StudentId>` in its internal state), or simple methods like `List<StudentId> presentStudent()` that just returns the list in its internal state, but what change from a `List<StudentId> getStudents()` its just the name).
So if the get method return something that is immutable who use it can't break the invariants of the aggregate.
If the method returns a mutable object that is part of the aggregate state, whoever access the object can query for that object and now can mutate something that stays inside the aggregate without passing for the right command methods, skipping invariants check (unless it is something wanted and managed).
Other possibility is that the object is created on the fly during the query and is not part of the aggregate state, so if someone access it, also if it is mutable, the aggregate is  safe.
In the end, get and set methods are seen as an ugly thing if you are a ddd extremist, but sometimes they can also be useful being a standard naming convention and some libraries work on this naming convention, so I don't see them bad, if they don't break the aggregate/entity responsibilities.

As last thing, when you say *In situation when we would like to operate on multiple Entities we introduce Service.*, this is true, but also a service should operate (mutate, save) on a single aggregate, but this is another topic .